# Pinterest thumbnail doesn't fit the screen

Tags: pinterest

I am using `www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=...` to create pin. A problem I found is the thumbnail doesn't fit the sharing screen:
[image]

Is there any solution to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Pinterest bug. You will not be able to fix this on your end since you do not control the styles in the /pin/create/button/ pop-up window.

I work at Pinterest and would be happy to report the bug to the right team for you if you can provide the full URL that you are using.

Comment: We haven't get online yet. It's found on our testing server